# Как сделать в PyQt5 автозаполнение QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

подскажите как сделать автозаполнение в QTextEdit. В QLineEdit с помощью QComplete  мне получилось сделать автозаполнение,  а с QTextEdit не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно сделать, или какой «приём» программирования здесь нужно использовать? Заранее спасибо! :)
Вот этот пример я нашёл на pythone который приводится на С+ [ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html ]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QStringListModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QKeySequence, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QCompleter, QMainWindow,
        QMessageBox, QTextEdit)

import customcompleter_rc # наверно слова для автозаполнения подставляются с 
    #отсюда


class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self._completer = None  # закрытая переменная

        self.setPlainText(
                "This TextEdit provides autocompletions for words that have "
                "more than 3 characters. You can trigger autocompletion "
                "using %s" % QKeySequence("Ctrl+E").toString(
                        QKeySequence.NativeText))
    # конец конструктора

    def setCompleter(self, c): # создали функцию для инициализации QCompleter
        if self._completer is not None:
            self._completer.activated.disconnect()

        self._completer = c

        c.setWidget(self) #виджет передаётся в использование
        c.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)  # устанавлеваем как 
        #будет показаны подсказки для автозамены(список или строка)
        c.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive) # устанавливает чувствительность к регистру
        c.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)  # сигнал и его обработка для всплывающего меню с автозаменой

    def completer(self):
        return self._completer

    def insertCompletion(self, completion): # слот созданный пользователем
        if self._completer.widget() is not self:
            return

        tc = self.textCursor()
        extra = len(completion) - len(self._completer.completionPrefix())
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)
        tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
        self.setTextCursor(tc)

    def textUnderCursor(self): #прегружен
        tc = self.textCursor()
        tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)

        return tc.selectedText()

    def focusInEvent(self, e): #прегружен
        if self._completer is not None:
            self._completer.setWidget(self)
        super(TextEdit, self).focusInEvent(e)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e): # перегружен
        if self._completer is not None and self._completer.popup().isVisible():
            # The following keys are forwarded by the completer to the widget.
            if e.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Escape, 
    Qt.Key_Tab, Qt.Key_Backtab):
                e.ignore()
                # Let the completer do default behavior.
                return

        isShortcut = ((e.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier) != 0 and e.key() == 
    Qt.Key_E)
        if self._completer is None or not isShortcut:
            # Do not process the shortcut when we have a completer.
            super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)

        ctrlOrShift = e.modifiers() & (Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.ShiftModifier)
        if self._completer is None or (ctrlOrShift and len(e.text()) == 0):
            return

        eow = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?,./;'[]\\-="
        hasModifier = (e.modifiers() != Qt.NoModifier) and not ctrlOrShift
        completionPrefix = self.textUnderCursor()

        if not isShortcut and (hasModifier or len(e.text()) == 0 or 
    len(completionPrefix) < 3 or e.text()[-1] in eow):
            self._completer.popup().hide()
            return

        if completionPrefix != self._completer.completionPrefix():
            self._completer.setCompletionPrefix(completionPrefix)
            self._completer.popup().setCurrentIndex(
                    self._completer.completionModel().index(0, 0))

        cr = self.cursorRect()
        cr.setWidth(self._completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0) + 
    self._completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
        self._completer.complete(cr)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.createMenu()

        self.completingTextEdit = TextEdit()
        self.completer = QCompleter(self)
        self.completer.setModel(self.modelFromFile(':/resources/wordlist.txt'))
        self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setWrapAround(True)
        self.completingTextEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.completingTextEdit)
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Completer")

    def createMenu(self):
        exitAction = QAction("Exit", self)
        aboutAct = QAction("About", self)
        aboutQtAct = QAction("About Qt", self)

        exitAction.triggered.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        aboutAct.triggered.connect(self.about)
        aboutQtAct.triggered.connect(QApplication.instance().aboutQt)

        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("File")
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        helpMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("About")
        helpMenu.addAction(aboutAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(aboutQtAct)

    def modelFromFile(self, fileName):
        f = QFile(fileName)
        if not f.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
            return QStringListModel(self.completer)

        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))

        words = []
        while not f.atEnd():
            line = f.readLine().trimmed()
            if line.length() != 0:
                try:
                    line = str(line, encoding='ascii')
                except TypeError:
                    line = str(line)

                words.append(line)

        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        return QStringListModel(words, self.completer)

    def about(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "About",
                "This example demonstrates the different features of the "
                "QCompleter class.")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[customcompleter_rc](https://yadi.sk/d/8B7Zt4bi4gnD2g) очень большой, в нём ну очень внушительный список, и всего 4 строчки кода

```
def qInitResources():
QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, 
      qt_resource_data)
def qCleanupResources():
    QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, 
      qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
qInitResources()
```

я  на него ссылку оставлю.

Мне не понятно, как подставить в этот пример свой список для автозаполнения, и обязательно ли keyPressEvent переопределять? Ещё я заметил, что английский символ "Е" не вводится я подозреваю что как то игнорируют его.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956693/pyqt5-qtextedit-auto-completion . Можете переписать код с с++ на питон (там несложно: и там, и там qt), либо попробовать пример из ответа

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению, для меня я не знаю С++ мне тяжело понять этот код. А за вторую ссылку спасибо!!! Буду пробовать.

Comment: Нашёл пример по первой ссылке на Питоне, вот сам  исходник [1](https://yadi.sk/d/8UZkNQHaxr9q-g) и [2](https://yadi.sk/d/8B7Zt4bi4gnD2g)
Проблема с пониманием что происходит в keyPressEvent и как  подставить свой список для автозамены.

Comment: Подправьте вопрос, добавив сам код из тех двух ссылок и вашим новым вопросом -- так будет проще (кст, не знаю как другие, но мне удобно код смотреть на том же pastebin или gist.github.com, но не на файлообменниках)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, а теперь смотрите `self.completer.setModel(self.modelFromFile(':/resources/wordlist.txt'))` тут и подается список слов. `':/resources/wordlist.txt'` вот эта запись означает что файл берется из ресурсов.

Если вы посмотрите в `modelFromFile`, то увидите, что там вызывается общий код для работы с файлами, поэтому вы можете **не** использовать `customcompleter_rc`, а брать локальный файл (например, из папки с скриптом):

```
...
self.completer.setModel(self.modelFromFile('wordlist.txt'))
...
```

Смотря на код с `modelFromFile` вижу, что он не сложный и его можно адаптировать под список, например:

```
def modelFromList(self, words):
    return QStringListModel(words, self.completer)
```

ну, и вызвать его, например так:

```
words = ['hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'питон']
...
self.completer.setModel(self.modelFromList(words))
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось!!! Маленький нюанс :) что дописать что бы из всплывающего окошка, пробелом можно было выбрать подсказку.

Comment: @Drop86, судя по коду, всплывающее окошко это QCompleter и похоже нужно будет руками ловить клик на пробел (например, через установки фильтра событий) и отправлять сигнал `activated` с выбранным вариантом. Но так ли это нужно? Проверил на двух IDE (PyCharm и Netbeans) и там выбор слова через enter работает, а на пробел просто скрывается окно с подсказкой и добавляется пробел

Comment: ну тогда и так сойдёт :) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Drop86, кст, взял ваш пример и переделал (например, можно задавать чем вызывать автодополнение (поменял на ctrl+space)). Completer объединил с QTextEdit, убрал вызов параметров которые содержат дефолтные значения (например setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)), ну и многое по мелочи: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9d24c3a8f71a0c907dc40786cda99dd3ddce7898/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/CompletingTextEdit__QTextEdit_QCompleter.py#L30

Comment: И я вас похоже неправильно понял насчет пробела, чтобы у вас коде из вопроса на ctrl+space вызывалось нужно поменять `Qt.Key_E` на `Qt.Key_Space`

Comment: Спасибо! Спасибо! Спасибо! У меня нет слов БОЛЬШУЩЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!! Ну просто ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!  Очень помогли))